# Going two directions from a subpanel

Tags: electrical, wiring

I am attempting to install a new circuit from a subpanel that is a 20A, that will have 4 outlets and 3 lights.

From my limited understanding of how circuits are wired, this are typically done in series.  A wire goes to the first outlet, then the second, and so on.

However, in my case, it would be very convenient to do kind of a junction box above the subpanel, and go right to wire 3 of the outlets, and left to wire the remaining outlet and the lights.

Is this kind of thing allowed?  What is the proper term for this, I am having issues doing a search online.

This could obviously be solved by doing two different circuits, out of the subpanel but that seems kind of overkill for the load.

Comment: Household circuits are NOT "generally in series" - the cables may look that way, going from one outlet to another, but electrically they are in parallel (each 120V device directly between hot and neutral, NOT in series with other loads.)

Comment: @Ecnerwal you know this, but you are correct.  Duh on me.  If they were in series, and one thing went bad, then the rest of the circuit "downstream" would also be bad.  TY for the comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is fine, as long as the configuration is a "tree" and not a "ring" like i[n another question posted this same hour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/246806/why-would-i-have-a-gfci-protecting-a-loop-of-receptacles).

You do not need to use an intermediate junction box.  If it is more convenient, you can use the panel itself *as the junction box*.  Land both neutral wires on their own lugs on the neutral bar. If the breaker is labeled for 2 wires under its lug, you can place both wires there; otherwise pigtail.

Regardless the junction box can never be buried under building materials; it must be findable and accessible without tools or destruction.

Comment: TY.  Somehow I instinctively new it not to be a ring.  I think I can do what you say, have two wires coming from the CB.  But I will check first.  Does this make a difference if it is a GFI CB with pigtail?  Basically the whites would go to the CB, and the pig tail from the CB to the neutral bar, and the grounds to the ground bar.

Comment: @PeteB Yes, you've got it. Pigtail to the neutral bar, both circuit neutrals to the GFCI neutral.  By the way, stay with the correct breaker type for your panel - don't switch to a HOM breaker just because they allow double-tapping.  1" breakers are not actually interchangeable (they'll fit, but then, they'll arc).

Comment: Downvoter Some breakers are UL listed for 2 wires per screw. What's illegal in Canada is pigtailing a circuit *through* a panel that isn't served by that panel, i.e. extending through to a new subpanel. Pigtailing/wire nuts is fine when the wires' destination is this panel.

Answer (score 4):

There is no real reason why you can't put in a junction box, split a circuit, and go two different directions. It's done all the time. I never knew there was a proper term for this in 120V wiring.

Here's a hint. When designing circuits, make a sketch of the floor plan then start a the farthest point from the panel and work your way toward it. That gives you a visual of how to connect the devices in the most efficient manner.

Comment: The subpanel is already a junction box as well, so you would even be allowed to make your splice inside the junction box.